# Design question - Multiple classes with same functionality

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns

I have some things to clarify for myself, so please bear with me.

Let's say I want to have an object that will explode after a certain period of time. If the object explodes while the person is still holding it, you get killed.

Let's consider the following implementation:

```
public interface IKillable
{
    void Kill();
}

public interface IExplodable : IKillable
{
     float TimeLeft { get; set; }
     void Timer(float timeToExplode);
}

public abstract class Bomb: IExplodable
{
    public float TimeLeft { get; set; }

    public void Kill()
    {
        //Destroy the object
    }

    public void Timer(float timeLeft)
    {
        if (TimeLeft <= 0) {

            Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

What if I also want to add let's say a "Backpack" instead of "Bomb" that will have the exact same functionality or any other item that can explode (and kill)?

1. Is inheriting a "Backpack from Bomb" reasonable in this case?
2. Probably copying the code won't follow SOLID principles?

Comment: I can't understand clearly, the Backpack is exactly same with Bomb?

Comment: Because it can have the same functionality as Bomb (explode). I just gave the bad example..

Comment: Could you explane it more clrearly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you don't understand?

Comment: @SeyedRaoufModarresi The question is pretty clear to me, it seems that you don't understsand English too well? I am sorry if this is not the case, but it's not clear what you don't understand

Comment: If two classes are the same from functionality point of view, why you have decided to separate their implementation, you can leave them same.

Comment: @SeyedRaoufModarresi The question is that a Bomb has the same functionality (explodes and kills) as that of a BackPack, yet the two are different devices

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Exactly. Visually are different but have the same functionality (and maybe different exploding effects, sounds,..etc).

Comment: thank you @CamiloTerevinto for your clarification. I Had a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a base class that provides common functionality for objects is both common and recommended in Unity.

Instead of calling the class `Bomb`, call it something more generic, like `ExplodableDevice` (as @zmbq answered). I would, however, make it more explicit that the device explods due to a timer, so perhaps `TimerExplodableDevice`. Notice that the base class should inherit from `MonoBehaviour` as otherwise you wouldn't be able to use those objects fully (as c# doesn't allow multiple inheritance).

An example of such implementation would be:

```
public interface IKillable
{
    void Kill();
}

public interface IExplodable : IKillable
{
     float TimeLeft { get; set; }
     void Timer(float timeToExplode);
}

public abstract class TimerExplodableDevice: MonoBehaviour, IExplodable
{
    public float TimeLeft { get; set; }

    public virtual void Kill()
    {
        //Destroy the object
    }

    public virtual void Timer(float timeLeft)
    {
        if (TimeLeft <= 0) 
        {
            Kill();
        }
    }
}

// this should be in a "Devices" folder, or otherwise be called appropriately
public class Backpack : TimerExplodableDevice
{
    void Start()
    {
        TimeLeft = 100;
    }
}

// this should be in a "Devices" folder, or otherwise be called appropriately
public class Bomb : TimerExplodableDevice
{
    void Start()
    {
        TimeLeft = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped! :) Also, why do I need to extend from MonoB in this case?

Comment: @rootpanthera You don't *need* to, it's only if you want to that you should do it. It depends on the requirements

Answer (score 1):

You can create an abstract `ExplodableDevice` class and have `Bomb` and `Backpack` inherit from it.